# Symfony2 Create an entity from two databases in one repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository, entity

I have a legacy database from which I have to extract some data and provide it as xml. For that I chose Symfony2 but now I am stuck. I would like to create one entity object, but the problem is, the data for it is distributed in two databases´(on the same server). I don't want to rewrite what I already made, so the easiest way would be to load the other database connections EntityManager in the existing repository. This is where I'am stuck. How can I load an EntityManager in a repository that uses the other connection? And what is the easiest way to "fill-in" the rest of the data of the entity? (By the way, I've used native queries in the repositories, because the legacy database is really complex and does not obey to any rules of DB design). I would be appreciate any help.

Comment: So, you want an entity to have fields from two different databases? I think taht's not possible out of the box, maybe you can create a Proxy class that represents your entity, with the logic to go to both databases to load and save.

Comment: How to create a custom proxy? Could you link me to some info on that?

Answer (score 0):

You could manage a second database connection called 'legacy', linking to the same database

than you need to map the entities to your managed connections than you could access your legacy table => entity and do whatever you want to with it ;)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: I've done this already, but the problem is I can't link one entity from two entity managers. Can I?

Comment: Didn't tested this

but if this doesnt work you could make another entity and reference them by something like a "legacyID" (if you have something like that) 

doctrine than have to fetch the reference for this entity from where ever you configured it to fetch it